# Nginx internal redirect

Tags: domain-name-system, nginx

The background:
I have a client in control of a DNS server and a domain name, who once pointed his domain name X to my server. He can't make any more changes (he doesn't know how and he can't be bothered). I'm hosting a wordpress blog on my server for him.

Now, I'd like to stop hosting the blog on my server, and instead host it on a managed WP hosting server (called wpengine.com), but I can't ask the client to point his DNS to anything else, he won't do it.

So I need to achieve a redirection from my server, to WPENGINE, via server directives. I'm using Nginx. What I'd like to achieve is:

- DNS server points his domain X.com to my server Y
- my server Y redirects his domain X to wpengine server Z
- URL bar displays his domain X, while internally I load and show the Z server content

Also of note, WPENGINE does allow to use custom domains, but they use CNAME pointer (http://wpengine.com/support/how-to-configure-your-dns/). I'm just testing if I can bypass this via server forwarding.

Thanks for any help or pointers.

Comment: Don't do this. Your client is being utterly unreasonable and you should in no way attempt to accommodate this absurdity.

Comment: I know and you are right, but if there was a simple way to do it this way, I could be spared that discussion

Comment: You can do it, but then _you have to keep this server running forever_, just for this one person who can't be bothered to take one minute out of his day. I say he either changes his DNS now, or he changes his DNS later when his site is down because it's been moved. If he truly doesn't want to bother, then you could offer to manage the DNS for him.

Answer (score 1):

Is he paying you?

You can reverse proxy the morons domain to his other server using the below configuration.

**I highly suggest** that you scrape his website and create a transparent phishing version that collects any details on various form submissions, and point your reverse proxy to that periodically.

People need to learn exactly why they don't do this. I will help you with it if you need - tell me what his website is and I'll create a version that collects data, and give you a server IP to proxy from.

```
upstream idiot_server {
    server ipaddress;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 'idiots domain name';
    access_log /var/logs/idiot.log;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://idiot_server;
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header  Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_cache_valid 404 1m;
        proxy_cache_bypass $cookie_nocache $arg_nocache$arg_comment;
    }
}
```